# Composite of two fields contain a given quadratic extension, but each individual doesn't.

Tags: field-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

In fact, this question could be asked for arbitrary field extension. However, for simplicity I only ask the question for local field of characteristic 0. Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of padic field (we may assume p≠2 also for simplicity). Can we classify all the possible cases: $E_1/F$ and $E_2/F$ are finite extensions of F, both of which are disjoint from E, but the composite $E_1E_2$ (we may also assume $E_1,E_2$ being disjoint from each other so that $E_1E_2\cong E_1\otimes_{F}E_2$) in $\overline{F}$ contains $E$. The most famous example is given by the biquadratic extensions $K/F$ such that $E_1,E_2,E$ are three intermediate quadratic extensions of $F$. Is there any example beyond this? Can we give a description when this happens?

Comment: Consider an $S_3$ extension. There are $3$ subgroups of size $2$. The fixed fields of these subgroups are distinct degree $3$ extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. Take $E_1$ to be the unique degree $2$ subextension and $E_2$ to be on of the degree $3$ subextensions. Such things should happen for any $S_n$. I think this should be considered the rule rather than the exception - i.e., you'd be better asking for a condition when it *doesn't* happen.

Comment: @Mummy the turkey Sorry,I do not understand your comments well. There is only one degree 2 subextension, what is $E$ in this case?

Comment: sorry i missed the fact that $E$ has to be quadratic (in my example I was thinking that $E$ is one of the other degree $3$ extensions). But the idea holds similarly. Take a group $G$ with lots of index $2$ subgroups and a field $K$ such that $Gal(K/F) = G$ take $2$ fields whose compositum is $K$ but neither of which contain on of the degree $2$ subfields (e.g., take an odd degree $E_1$, and one of the other degree $2$ subextensions as $E_2$)

Comment: @ Mummy the turkey. I am still missing. My original guess to the question is that: $E_1$ and $E_2$ must contains $E_{1}^{'},E_{2}^{'}$ (both are quadratic over $F$), such that $E_{1}^{'},E_{2}^{'},E$ are three intermediate fields of a biquadratic extension $K$, just like the example I mentioned. But I can not prove it.